ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mesa.time'
so is the module python updated then how to fix it? downgrade mesa version?
I am working on my final assignment to create a model and simulation of invasive fish.
This is my first time trying to use stack overflow, I'm not good at finding documentation on the official site.

are you sure, that mesa is already installed in your current python environment? Try pip list in your console.
